# Change image based on Radio Button Selection in HTML/JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, image, dom-events

I have a project where I am to have an image displayed for three different radio button groups.  If a radio button is selected, the image needs to change to a different pic.  I have the rest of the code doing what I need it to, except this part.  I am technically also suppose to change the radio button font color and bold it when it is selected as well.  I haven't gotten to even attempt that because I cant get the image switching to work.  Here is my code.  Any input will be helpful.  The code starts with a function to do some calculations based on the radio button selection.  it then goes into some validation parts, submission and clearing.  The image stuff I did is closer to the bottom before the body of the HTML.  Like I said, any input at all will be greatly appreciated.

```
<html>
 <head>
    <title> Final Project Order Form </title>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        var prices = new Object();
        function updateTotal () {
            var total = 0.00;
            for (var price in prices) {
                total += parseInt(prices[price]);
            }
            document.getElementById("total").value = total;   // Add the id "total" to the input field
        }
        function doClear()
            {
                document.AddressForm.customer.value = "";
                document.AddressForm.address.value = "";
                document.AddressForm.city.value= "";
                document.AddressForm.state.options[0].selected = "true";
                document.AddressForm.zip.value = "";
                document.AddressForm.phone.value= "";
                document.AddressForm.email.value= "";
            document.AddressForm.total.value= "";

                document.OrderForm.cases[0].checked = false;
                document.OrderForm.cases[1].checked = false;
                document.OrderForm.cases[2].checked = false;

                document.OrderForm.monitors[0].checked = false;
                document.OrderForm.monitors[1].checked = false;
                document.OrderForm.monitors[2].checked = false;

                document.OrderForm.printers[0].checked = false;
                document.OrderForm.printers[1].checked = false;
                document.OrderForm.printers[2].checked = false;

                return;
            }

            function validateText()
            {
                var transcribed = true;
                
                var notification = "";
                    
                var customer = document.AddressForm.customer.value;
                var address = document.AddressForm.address.value;
                var city = document.AddressForm.city.value;
                var state = document.AddressForm.state.value;
                var zip = document.AddressForm.zip.value;
                var phone = document.AddressForm.phone.value;
                var email = document.AddressForm.email.value;
                    
                if (customer.length == 0) 
                {
                    transcribed = false;
                    alert("Please enter your name.");
                    return;
                }
                    
                if (address.length == 0) 
                {
                    transcribed = false;
                    alert("Please enter your address.");
                    return;
                }
                    
                if (city.length == 0) 
                {
                    transcribed = false;
                    alert("Please enter your city.");
                    return;
                }
                    
                if (zip.length == 0) 
                {
                    transcribed = false;
                    alert("Please enter your five digit zip.");
                    return;
                }
                    
                if (phone.length == 0) 
                {
                    transcribed = false;
                    alert("Please enter your phone.");
                    return;
                }
                    
                if (email.length == 0) 
                {
                    transcribed = false;
                    alert("Please enter your email.");
                    return;
                }
                    
                if (!transcribed)
                {
                    alert(notification);
                }
                    
                return transcribed;
            }
                
            function validateEmail()
                {
                    var email = document.AddressForm.email.value;
                
                    var pass = true;
                    
                    if (email.indexOf('@') == -1)
                    {
                        pass = false;
                    }
                    
                    else if (email.indexOf('@') == 0)
                    {
                        pass = false;
                    }
                    
                    else if (email.indexOf('@') == email.length - 1)
                    {
                        pass = false;
                    }
                                
                    return pass;
                }

                /*
                    Checking all the format functions
                */              
                function validatePhone()
                {
    
                    var phone = document.AddressForm.phone.value;
        
                    if(isTenDigits(phone) || isTwelveAndBrackets(phone) || isTwelveAndDashes(phone) || isBracketsAndDash(phone))
                        return true;
        
                    return false;
        
                }
    
                /*
                    Checking all the Zip is correct
                */  
                function validateZip()
                {
    
                    var zip = document.AddressForm.zip.value;
        
                    if(isfiveDigits(zip))
                        return true;
        
                    return false;
        
                }
    
                /*
                    Checking the 10-digit format
                */
                function isTenDigits(phone)
                {
        
                    if(phone.length != 10)
                        return false;
            
                    var pass = true;

                    for (var i = 0;i < phone.length; i++)
                    {
                        var c = phone.charAt(i);
                        if (!isDigit(c))
                        {
                            pass = false;
                        }
                    }

                    return pass;
                }
    
                /*
                Checking the (xxx)xxxxxxx format
                */
                function isTwelveAndBrackets(phone)
                {
    
                    if(phone.length != 12)
                        return false;
        
                    var pass = true;

                    for (var i = 0;i < phone.length; i++)
                    {
                        var c = phone.charAt(i);
                        var pos = i + 1;
                        if(i == 0)
                        {
                            if(c != '(')
                            {
                                pass = false;
                            }
                        }
                        else if(i == 4)
                        {
                            if(c != ')')
                            {
                                pass = false;
                            }
                        }
                        else 
                        {
                            if (!isDigit(c))
                            {
                                pass = false;
                            }
                        }
                    }

                    return pass;
                }
    
                /*
                Checking the xxx-xxx-xxxx format
                */
                function isTwelveAndDashes(phone)
                {
    
                    if(phone.length != 12)
                        return false;
                    var pass = true;
        
                    for (var i = 0;i < phone.length; i++)
                    {
                        var c = phone.charAt(i);
                        var pos = i + 1;
                        if(i == 3)
                        {
                            if(c != '-')
                            {
                                pass = false;
                            }
                        }
                        else if(i == 7)
                            {
                                if(c != '-')
                                {
                                    pass = false;
                                }
                            }
                            else 
                            {
                                if (!isDigit(c))
                                {
                                    pass = false;
                                }
                            }
                    }

                    return pass;
                }
            
                /*
                Checking the (xxx)-xxx-xxxx format
                */
                function isBracketsAndDash(phone) 
                {
                    if (phone.length != 13)
                        return false;
                    
                    var pass = true;
                                       
                    for (var i = 0;i < phone.length; i++)
                    {
                        var c = phone.charAt(i);
                        var pos = i + 1;
                        if(i == 0)
                        {
                            if(c != '(')
                            {
                                pass = false;
                            }
                        }
                        else if(i == 4)
                        {
                            if(c != ')')
                            {
                                pass = false;
                            }
                        }       
                        else if(i == 8)
                            {
                                if(c != '-')
                                {
                                    pass = false;
                                }
                            }
                            else 
                            {
                                if (!isDigit(c))
                                {
                                    pass = false;
                                }
                            }
                    }
  
                    return pass; 
                }  
                
                /*
                Validate Zip is 5 digits and numerical
                */
                function isfiveDigits(zip)
                {
        
                    if(zip.length != 5)
                        return false;
            
                    var pass = true;

                    for (var i = 0;i < zip.length; i++)
                    {
                        var c = zip.charAt(i);
                        if (!isDigit(c))
                        {
                            pass = false;
                        }
                    }

                    return pass;
                }
                
                function isDigit(num) 
                {
                    if (num.length>1)
                    {
                        return false;
                    }
                    
                    var string="1234567890";
                    
                    if (string.indexOf(num)!=-1)
                    {
                        return true;
                    }
                    return false;
                }               
                
            function printCaseRadio()
                {
                    var tower;
                    
                    if (document.OrderForm.cases[0].checked)
                    {
                        tower = "Desktop Case ($500) <br />";
                    }
                    else if (document.OrderForm.cases[1].checked)
                        {
                            tower = "Mini-Tower Case ($600) <br />";
                        }
                        else if (document.OrderForm.cases[2].checked)
                            {
                                tower = "Full Tower Case ($700) <br />";
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                tower = "No Case Selected <br/>"
                            }
                    return tower;
                }
            
            function printMonitorRadio()
                {
                    var monitors;
                    
                    if (document.OrderForm.monitors[0].checked)
                    {
                        monitors = "17inch LCD Flat Screen (250.00) <br />";
                    }
                    else if (document.OrderForm.monitors[1].checked)
                        {
                            monitors = "19inch LCD Flat Screen (300.00) <br />";
                        }
                        else if (document.OrderForm.monitors[2].checked)
                            {
                                monitors = "21inch LCD Flat Screen (350.00) <br />";
                            }
                            else 
                            {
                                monitors = "No Monitor Selected <br/>"
                            }
                    return monitors;
                }
        
        function printPrinterRadio()
            {
                var printers;
                
                if (document.OrderForm.printers[0].checked)
                {
                    printers = "Inkjet Printer (100.00) <br />";
                }
                else if (document.OrderForm.printers[1].checked)
                    {
                        printers = "Laser Printer (250.00) <br />";
                    }
                    else if (document.OrderForm.printers[2].checked)
                        {
                            printers = "Laser Printer (250.00) <br />";
                        }
                        else 
                        {
                            printers = "No Printer Selected <br/>"
                        }
                
                return printers;
            }   

        function doSubmit()
            {
            
                /*
                Submitting Dropdown selection
                */
                var ind = document.AddressForm.state.options.selectedIndex; 
                var value = document.AddressForm.state.options[ind].value;
            
            
                /* 
                Checking the phone number is correct
                */              
                if(validatePhone()  == false)
                {
                    var message = "Phone number must be in one of the following formats:\n";
                    message += "ddd-ddd-dddd\n";
                    message += "dddddddddd\n";
                    message += "(ddd)ddddddd\n";
                    message += "(ddd)ddd-dddd";
        
                    alert(message);
                }
                
                /* 
                Checking the zip is correct
                */
                if(validateZip()  == false)
                {
                    var message = "Zip must be five digits and can only contain numbers";
        
                    alert(message);
                }
                
                /* 
                Checking the email is correct
                */
    
                if(validateEmail() == false)
                {
                    var message = "Email must contain @ except in the first and last position.";
                    alert(message);
                }
                
        

                
                
                /* 
                Checking that all validation steps work, prior to printing out detail
                */                  
            
                if (validateText() && validateEmail()&&validatePhone()&& validateZip())
                {
                    
                    var confirmation = "";
                    var Namestring =  document.AddressForm.customer.value.charAt(0).toUpperCase()+document.AddressForm.customer.value.substring(1).toLowerCase();
                    var Citystring =  document.AddressForm.city.value.charAt(0).toUpperCase()+document.AddressForm.city.value.substring(1).toLowerCase();
                    
                    confirmation += "Your order has been submitted.<br /><br />";
                    confirmation += "Name: " + Namestring + "<br />";
                    confirmation += "Address: " + document.AddressForm.address.value + "<br />";
                    confirmation += "City: " + Citystring + "<br />";
                    confirmation += "State: " + value + "<br />";
                    confirmation += "Zip: " + document.AddressForm.zip.value + "<br />";
                    confirmation += "Phone: " + document.AddressForm.phone.value + "<br />";
                    confirmation += "Email: " + document.AddressForm.email.value + "<br />";
                    
                    
                    var casepick = printCaseRadio();
                    
                    confirmation += casepick;
                    
                    var monitorpick = printMonitorRadio();
                    
                    confirmation += monitorpick;
                    
                    var printerpick = printPrinterRadio();
                    
                    confirmation += printerpick;
                    
                    confirmation += "Total: " + document.AddressForm.total.value + "<br />";
                    
                    document.write(confirmation);
                    
                    
                }
                return;
            }
        function getRadioValue(radioName)
        {
            for (var i = 0; i < radioName.length; i++) 
            {
                if (radioName[i].checked == true) 
                {
                    return radioName[i].value;
                }
            }
        }
        
        var caseIndex=0;
        function displayCase()
        {
            if (document.OrderForm.cases[0].checked = true)
            {
                caseIndex=0;
            }
            else if (document.OrderForm.cases[0].checked = true)
                {
                    caseIndex=1;
                }
                else if (document.OrderForm.cases[0].checked = true)
                {
                    caseIndex=2;
                }
            document.casepic.src = casePics[caseIndex];
        }
        
        var monitorIndex =0;
        function displayMonitor()
        {
            if (document.OrderForm.monitors[0].checked = true)
            {
                monitorIndex =0;
            }
            else if (document.OrderForm.monitors[1].checked = true)
                {
                    monitorIndex =1;
                }
                else if (document.OrderForm.monitors[2].checked = true)
                {
                    monitorIndex =2;
                }
                document.monitorpic.src = monitorPics[monitorIndex];            
        }
        
        var printerIndex =0;
        function displayPrinter()
        {
            if (document.OrderForm.printers[0].checked = true)
            {
                printerIndex =0;
            }
            else if (document.OrderForm.printers[1].checked = true)
                {
                    printerIndex =1;
                }
                else if (document.OrderForm.printers[2].checked = true)
                {
                    printerIndex =2
                }
            document.printpic.src = printerPics[printerIndex];
        
        }
    

        function startup()
        {
        
            var casePics = new Array(3);
            casePics[0]= new Image;
            casepics[0].src = "case1.jpg";
            casePics[1]= new Image;
            casepics[1].src = "case2.jpg";
            casePics[2]= new Image;
            casepics[2].src = "case3.jpg";
        
            var monitorPics = new Array(3);
            monitorPics[0]= new Image;
            monitorpics[0].src = "monitor1.jpg";
            monitorPics[1]= new Image;
            monitorpics[1].src = "monitor2.jpg";
            monitorPics[2]= new Image;
            monitorpics[2].src = "monitor3.jpg";
        
            var printerPics = new Array(3);
            printerPics[0]= new Image;
            printerpics[0].src = "printer1.jpg";
            printerPics[1]= new Image;
            printerpics[1].src = "printer2.jpg";
            printerPics[2]= new Image;
            printerpics[2].src = "printer3.jpg";
        
            displayCase();
            displayMonitor();
            displayPrinter();
        
        }
</script>
```

```
<body onLoad = "startup()" >  
    <h1 align="center">Computer System Order Form</h1>  
    <table border="black" cellpadding="10px" align="center">        
        <tr>
            <td>
                <table cellpadding="10px">
                <form name="OrderForm">
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            Computer Case Style:</br>
                            <input type="radio" name="cases" value="500.00" onchange="javascript:prices['cases'] = this.value; updateTotal();" /> Desktop Case (500.00) </br>
                            <input type="radio" name="cases" value="600.00" onchange="javascript:prices['cases'] = this.value; updateTotal();" /> Mini-Tower Case (600.00) </br>
                            <input type="radio" name="cases" value="700.00" onchange="javascript:prices['cases'] = this.value; updateTotal();" /> Full-Tower Case (700.00) </br>
                        </td>
                    
                        <td>
                            <img name="casepic" src="case1.jpg" width="125" height="125">   
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            Computer Monitor: <br/>
                            <input type="radio" name="monitors" value="250.00" onchange="javascript:prices['monitors'] = this.value; updateTotal();"  /> 17" LCD Flat Screen (250.00) </br>
                            <input type="radio" name="monitors" value="300.00" onchange="javascript:prices['monitors'] = this.value; updateTotal();"  /> 19" LCD Flat Screen (300.00) </br>
                            <input type="radio" name="monitors" value="350.00" onchange="javascript:prices['monitors'] = this.value; updateTotal();" /> 21" LCD Flat Screen (350.00) </br>
                        </td>
                    
                        <td>
                            <img name="monitorpic" src="monitor1.jpg" width="125" height="125">
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            Computer Printer:<br/>
                            <input type="radio" name="printers" value="100.00" onchange="javascript:prices['printers'] = this.value; updateTotal();"  /> Inkjet Printer (100.00) </br>
                            <input type="radio" name="printers" value="250.00" onchange="javascript:prices['printers'] = this.value; updateTotal();" /> Laser Printer (250.00) </br>
                            <input type="radio" name="printers" value="350.00" onchange="javascript:prices['printers'] = this.value; updateTotal();" /> Color Printer (350.00) </br>
                        </td>
                   
                        <td>
                            <img name="printpic" src="printer1.jpg" width="125" height="125"/>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </form>
                </table>            
    
            </td>
            
            <td>
                <table padding="10px">
                    <tr>
                    <form name="AddressForm">
                        <td>
                            Total System Price:
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            $<input type="text" name="total" readonly value="0.00" size="8" id="total">
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            &nbsp;
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            &nbsp;
                        </td>
                
                    </tr>
                    
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            &nbsp;
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            Full Name:
                        </td>
                        
                        <td>
                            <input type="text" name="customer" />
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            Street Address:
                        </td>
                    
                        <td>
                            <input type="text" name="address" />
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            City:
                        </td>
                        
                        <td>
                            <input type="text" name="city" />
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            State:
                        </td>
                        
                        <td>
                            <select name="state">
                                <option value=""></option>
                                <option value="DE">DE</option>
                                <option value="NJ">NJ</option>
                                <option value="NY">NY</option>
                                <option value="PA">PA</option>
                            </select>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            Zip:
                        </td>
                        
                        <td>
                            <input type="text" name="zip" />
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            Phone Number:
                        </td>
                        
                        <td>
                            <input type="text" name="phone" />
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    
                    <tr>
                    
                        <td>
                            Email Address:
                        </td>
                        
                        <td>
                            <input type="text" name="email">
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    </form>
                
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            &nbsp;
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            <input type="button" value="Submit Order" onClick="doSubmit()" />
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <input type="button" value="Clear Form" onClick="doClear()"  />
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </table>           
            </td>       
        </tr>   
    </table>
            
</body>
```

Comment: Can you be specific?  Post only the relevant code, this too big.

Comment: i do not know what jquery is.  if that is another type of html language, then i don't think i am allowed to use that.  I will repost the relevant code, sorry, i thought it wouldn't work if the other functions were not defined.

Comment: I tried to shorten the code and each time i get warnings to add context.  I am not sure what the error is as its the same post but i deleted off unnecessary code.  perhaps I need to delete this question and start again.

Answer (score 3):

This is Just a sample code , which changes the background of a div based on the radio button selection

**HTML**

```
<input type="radio"  name="ch" value="http://www.menucool.com/slider/prod/image-slider-1.jpg" onClick="CB(this.value);" />
URL 1
<input type="radio"  name="ch" value="http://www.menucool.com/slider/prod/image-slider-3.jpg" onClick="CB(this.value);" />
URL 2
<div id="back">
</div>
```

**JAVASCRIPT**

```
function CB(bg) {
var url;
    if(bg=="yourvalue1")
    {
        url="http://www.menucool.com/slider/prod/image-slider-1.jpg";
    document.getElementById("ecard").style.backgroundImage = "url(" + url + ")";
    }
    else if(bg=="yourvalue2")
    {
    url="http://www.menucool.com/slider/prod/image-slider-3.jpg";
    document.getElementById("ecard").style.backgroundImage = "url(" + url + ")";            
    }
    }
```

**[FIDDLE TO PLAY](http://jsfiddle.net/F6zPc/8/)**

Comment: Thank you.  I have found this method online in searching but i run into one problem, that maybe is not a big deal.  I define the value of each radio button for another function that has to calculate the total of the selections.  is there a way to do two values on a radio button?

Comment: @user3036140 Its okay , you can have your existing values and check them in the js function, I just edited my answer like that , check the fiddle

Comment: Thanks, I looked at the fiddle and i gave it a shot.  here is the code i came up with.  

function CB(bg) {
   
     if(bg=="500.00")
     {
     document.getElementById("casepic").src = casePics[0].src;
     }
     else if(bg=="600.00")
     {
      document.getElementById("casepic").src = casePics[1].src;           
    
     }
     else if(bg=="700.00")
     {
      document.getElementById("casepic").src = casePics[2].src;           
    
     }
   }
i am still doing something wrong and i think it has to do with the document.getelementid part.

Comment: i think i am finding my error may be with the image array for case pics.  i just tried to see if i could call an image and nothing happened.

Comment: i found it. thank you.  it was my array.  I did it without the array and seems to work now.

Comment: @BharathR Why the images are shown continuously rather than one appearance. And how can i correct it? Newbee to html and javascripts.